# Need to create Indices (Index) for Sqlite3 Database

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am using C++ - sqlite3 for creating a Database. The database is regularly updated and after point of time becomes very large in size (in GB's) which make it very slow when we execute query (via C++ syntax).

I read in sqlite site that for large Database tables we can create Index tables for optimization and speeding up database queries. I now have successfully written an index syntax just after creating my database.

```
sqlQuery << "CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS 'IdxNode_Val' ON node_values (aliasDevice,aliasProperty,sourceTimestamp);";
int rc = sqlite3_exec(this->db, sqlQuery.str().c_str(), 0, 0, &zErrMsg);
```

**Query**:
The question is since my database gets updated on a daily basis (new entries added), will the index table also be updated automatically or should I have to write a syntax to update the index table just after my "*insert into database*" syntax?

Thanks & best Regards
rG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database automatically updates indexes.